# Calling parent class method of template class with different signature but same name doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class foo {
    public:
        T add(T x, T y) { return x + y; }
};

template <class T>
class bar : public foo<T> {
    public:
        T add(T x, T y, T z) {
            T result;
            result = this->add(x, y) + z;
            return result;
        }
};

int main() {
    bar<int> a;
    std::cout << a.add(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Has the following error:

```
b.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T bar<T>::add(T, T, T) [with T = int]’:
b.cpp:21:31:   required from here
b.cpp:14:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘bar<int>::add(int&, int&)’
             result = this->add(x, y) + z;
                                      ^
b.cpp:14:38: note: candidate is:
b.cpp:12:11: note: T bar<T>::add(T, T, T) [with T = int]
         T add(T x, T y, T z) {
           ^
b.cpp:12:11: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
```

Everything is fine if I replace `this->add(x, y)` with `foo<T>::add`, or if I change the name of `foo<T>::add` to something else, like `foo<T>::addr`. Why does the inheritance work if there is no name clash, but doesn't work when there is, even though the function signatures are different?